# Inserting build target using build.xml only?

Tags: android, ant, compilation, proguard

I have a build.xml which is capable of compiling and optimizing if I run the build targets individually - "ant compile" followed by "and optimize".

The problem is, that I want to run "ant release" which would normally do Everything necessary to produce the release binary, but I need to insert a build target to the chain - the target is called "optimize" and it runs a proguard optimize/shrinker against the class files just before the "dex" stage builds the byte code.

The template file /opt/android-sdk-linux_x86/platforms/android-8/templates/android_rules.xml contains the following rule, which I could modify to say "depends="compile,optimize" " But I don't want to have to re-modify the file for every different SDK that comes out (with a new android_rules.xml file each time).

```
<!-- Converts this project's .class files into .dex files -->
<target name="-dex" depends="compile">
    <dex-helper />
</target>
```

Is there an alternative to modifying the template xml and instead putting all compile rules into the build.xml?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not use the post-compile hook in the template `build.xml` file? It reads:

```
[This is typically used for code obfuscation.
 Compiled code location: ${out.classes.absolute.dir}
 If this is not done in place, override ${out.dex.input.absolute.dir}]
<target name="-post-compile">
</target>
```

Given that it's there explicitly asking for modification, I would think that it would be supported across sdk versions.

To see the full auto-generated `build.xml` file for your project you may need to run `android update project`.

Comment: Oh man this is perfect. Didn't even realize it was there. Thanks! - tested - it works! I simply added a depend to this attribute of my build.xml: <target name="-post-compile" depends="optimize"></target>

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you missed it:

As of SDK Tools Rev 8, Proguard support is built in. You just need to add the line

```
proguard.config=proguard.cfg
```

to your default.properties (and have a proguard.cfg file of course, where you set up your obfuscation rules)

You don't need to add any other targets.

(This is true in the Windows version anyway, I imagine it's the same for Linux. The 'rules' xml is now called main_rules.xml)

Comment: I gave it a whirl, but Fedora 14 is still sporting ant 1.7 (not the 1.8 required by the new sdk). Alas I will have to wait til they catch up, but I'm looking forward to using this much simpler method. Thank you NickT.